# Stuck in the following dp code

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming, prime-factoring

I wrote the following dp code for finding the prime factors of a number.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define max 1000001
using namespace std;
vector <int> prime;
vector<bool> isprime(max,true);
vector<bool> visited(max,false);
vector<int> data(max,-1);
void dp(int n,int last)
{
    if(n >= max || visited[n])
        return;
    visited[n] = true;
    for(int i = last;i<prime.size();i++)
    {
        if(n*prime[i] >= max || data[n*prime[i]] != -1)
            return;
        data[n*prime[i]] = prime[i];
        dp(n*prime[i],i);
    }
}
int main()
{
    isprime[1] = false;
    data[1] = 1;
    for(int i = 4;i<max;i += 2)
        isprime[i] = false;
    for(int i = 3; i*i< max;i += 2)
    {
        for(int j = i*i; j < max;j += i)
            isprime[j] = false;
    }
    prime.push_back(2);
    data[2] = 2;
    for(int i =3;i<max;i += 2)
        if(isprime[i])
        {
            prime.push_back(i);
            data[i] = i;
        }

    for(int i = 0;i<prime.size();i++)
    {
        dp(prime[i],i);
    }
        cout<<"...1\n";
    for(int i = 2;i<=8000;i++)
    {
        cout<<i<<" :- ";
        int temp = i;
        while(temp!= 1)
        {
            cout<<data[temp]<<" ";
            temp = temp/data[temp];
        }
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Here, `last` is the last index of prime number `n`.
But I am getting segmentation fault for this, when I change `max` to `10001`, it runs perfectly. I'm not getting why is this happening since the data-structures used are 1-d vectors which can hold values up to 10^6 easily.

Comment: Check to see if `n*prime[i]` overflows?  Also make sure it does not exceed the `size` of `data`?

Comment: @NathanOliver
I i checked inside for loop

Comment: Perhaps n*prime[i] overflowed to a negative number?

Comment: Is there any question in your post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your program out using GDB. The segfault is taking place at this line:

```
if(n*prime[i] >= max || data[n*prime[i]] != -1)
```

In your first ever call to DP in your for loop, where you call dp(2,0), the recursive calls eventually generate this call: dp(92692,2585).

```
92692 * 2585 = 239608820
```

This number is larger than a 32 bit integer can hold, so the r-value generated by the integer multiplication of those two numbers overflows and becomes negative. nprime[i] becomes negative, so your first condition of the above loop fails, and the second is checked. data[n * prime[i]] is accessed, and since n*prime[i] is negative, your program accesses invalid memory and segfaults. To fix this, simply change n to a long long in your parameter list and you should be fine.

```
void dp(long long n, int last)
```

Comment: thanks it did..
now it's able to do calculations for most of the values..
but it is still unable to get into some of the values..
for ex :- it is traversing for 2 upto 6427..
next prime is 6449 which is not being reached and so value 2*6449 i.e. 12898 is marked  as -1...